# How can I show UIActionSheet to confirm moving back in Navigation View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, navigation, uiactionsheet

Using Xcode I have View A that navigates to View B.

Upon pressing the Back UIBarButtonItem, I'm trying present the user with a UIActionSheet to confirm navigation to move back to View A.

What do I need to do in code to stop the view from navigating back and then (depending on user input) move back or stay on the current screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add a backbutton programmatically.

eg.

```
UIButton *backBtn= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,54,30)];
 [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];   
[backBtn release];
 [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:backBarButton];
 [backBarButton release];

  //backButtonPressed is the selector for backBtn
```

Then present you ActionSheet from that selector and based on user either navigate to previous viewController or dont.

To navigate to previous page, use popViewMethod.

`

Comment: I've implemented the "backButtonPressed:" method as well as "popToRootViewControllerAnimated", however the UIBarButton is invisible :(

Answer (score 1):

You should not present UIActionSheet for every other action.It would be better to use UIAlertView for this purpose. According to Apple UIActionsheet Guidelines :-

Provide alternate ways a task can be completed. An action sheet allows you to provide a range of choices that make sense in the context of the current task, without giving these choices a permanent place in the user interface.

Get confirmation before completing a potentially dangerous task. An action sheet prompts users to think about the potentially dangerous effects of the step they’re about to take and gives them some alternatives. This type of communication is particularly important on iOS-based devices because sometimes users tap controls without meaning to.

for UIAlertView :-

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert View"
                                                            message:@"Do You want to go back to previous screen?"
                                                            delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"YES",nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"THE 'NO' BUTTON WAS PRESSED");
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"THE 'YES' BUTTON WAS PRESSED");
    }
}
```

Implement this on action of back button of UINavigationController.According to the buttons pressed "YES" or "NO" , you can allow navigation.Also conform to UIAlerrtVIewDelegate protocol.